# Filtering an array by using values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays. One holds products, the other holds filters (Shirts, Pants, etc).  All products have a type property which could be shirts, pants, etc, corresponding to the filters.

I'm trying to make a selector that will return a new array missing any of the products that have a type that matches any of the filters.

```
export function filterProducts(products, filters) {
  return products.filter((item) => {
    return item.type === "hat";
  });
};
```

Similar to this, except instead obviously checking against every filter, not just "hat".  I can think of some janky ways to implement this, but I'm trying to figure out something more elegant.  I know I have to loop inside of a loop, but I can't quite get it to work correctly. ES6/lodash, etc are fine.

Comment: You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof), or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which are all array methods.

Comment: `item => filters.includes(item.type)`?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to keep the ones matching the filters or the other way around? Your post contradicts itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `filters` is an array of strings containing the types you are looking for, you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to search the `filters` array to filter it.

```js
var products = [
    {
      name: 'Foo',
      type: 'hat'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      type: 'shirt'
    },
    {
      name: 'Baz',
      type: 'pants'
    },
    {
      name: 'Foobar',
      type: 'hat'
    },
    {
      name: 'Falsy Type',
      type: ''
    },
  ],
  filters = ['hat', 'pants', ''];

function filterProducts(products, filters) {
  return products.filter((item) => {
    return !filters.some(filter => item.type === filter);
  });
};

console.log(filterProducts(products, filters));
```

Comment: I actually gave the wrong code snippet and it probably made answering my question confusing.  I ended up using:

`!filters.find(filter => item.type === filter)`

Which gave me the desired result.

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: @Ian Ah, I seem to have glossed over the "missing any" in the text. I've updated the answer to reflect what you were going for.

Comment: No, you should use `some` instead of `find` to check whether an element exists in an array. Imagine `item.type` being falsy…

Comment: @Bergi `find` would only fail if there was both a falsy `item.type` and a matching falsy item in `filters`; since `filters` is an array of non-empty strings (thus always truthy), barring a typo `find` works. That said, you're right that `some` is a be better fit for this, it makes it more bullet-proof. I've updated the example.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, if you care about outdated browsers that don't support `some`, there's only IE8 and that would even need a polyfill for `indexOf`

Comment: @Bergi Wow. I forgot IE8 didn't support `indexOf`... coding some things in pre-ES5 browsers was so much more painful sometimes. IE8 doesn't support `filter` either, you'd probably just have to use plain loops instead... working on updating the answer.

Comment: Nah, let's just forget about those ancient times. Who really needs to support IE8 in these days knows about those pitfalls, no need to mention them in every answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this !

```
'use strict'
const filters = ['hat','shirt','pant'];
const products = [{
                    sku: 101,
                    type: 'hat'
                 }, {
                    sku: 102,
                    type: 'hat'
                 }, {
                    sku: 103,
                    type: 'shirt'
                 }, {
                    sku: 104,
                    type: 'pant'
                 }, {
                    sku: 101,
                    type: 'pant'
                 }, {
                    sku: 101,
                    type: 'shirt'
                 }]


const filterize = function (products, filters){
    let map = {};
    filters.forEach(function(filter){
        map[filter] = [];
    })
    products.forEach(function(product){
        if(typeof map[product.type] !== undefined){
            map[product.type].push(product);
        }
    })
    return map;
}


console.log(filterize(products, filters));
```

This will return a map with your filters as keys and values as the product list corresponding to the filter. Sample output below :

```
{ hat: [ { sku: 101, type: 'hat' }, { sku: 102, type: 'hat' } ],
  shirt: [ { sku: 103, type: 'shirt' }, { sku: 101, type: 'shirt' } ],
  pant: [ { sku: 104, type: 'pant' }, { sku: 101, type: 'pant' } ] }
```